# In the case of the Ricci flow, the symmetries of the flow are scalings and diffeomorphisms

Tags: ricci-flow, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can anyone help me and prove that **in the case of the Ricci flow, the symmetries of the flow are scalings and diffeomorphisms**?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401943/in-the-case-of-the-ricci-flow-the-symmetries-of-the-flow-are-scalings-and-diffe

Comment: any textbook will have this proof, see for example

http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=3642162851

Comment: @Carlo:  Most textbooks on Ricci flow will indeed show that scalings and diffeomorphisms are symmetries of the PDE, but I am not so sure that there are many books that show the converse, namely, that any symmetry of the PDE system (once this has been properly defined) is necessarily a combination of scalings and diffeomorphisms. 

Comment: Could someone say what the definition of a symmetry of the flow is? My reaction to the question was: isn't that the definition of a symmetry?

Comment: Andrews & Hopper (link above, page 66) _define_ a symmetry as a diffeomorphism that is an isometry of the initial metric, and then prove that Ricci flow preserves this symmetry (so the isometry persists for positive time). I imagine one could more generally define a symmetry as any operation that transforms one solution into another solution. For the vacuum Einstein equations it has been proven that diffeomorophisms (with scaling) exhaust all symmetries:

http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9404030

Comment: @Deane:  I took 'the Ricci flow' to mean the PDE system itself which one can think of as a submanifold of an appropriate jet bundle $J$ over $M\times\mathbb{R}$.  Then a 'symmetry' would a self-diffeomorphism of $J$ that carries solutions to solutions (thought of via their $k$-jet graphs).  @Carlo:  You probably want to be more precise about what 'operations' you allow.  Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all Ricci-flat metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\sigma:\mathcal{S}\to\mathcal{S}$ be *any* mapping whatsoever.  This is an 'operation that transforms one solution to another solution', no?

Answer (score 1):

I apologise first for submitting this comment as an answer (not enough MO-cred to comment) and second for submitting a question rather than a comment:

What I can gather from the comments above is that the symmetries of the Ricci flow are completely understood: Every `symmetry' of the Ricci flow is a spatial diffeomorphism combined with scaling (and every such combination is a symmetry). My question is whether the problem is also solved for the mean curvature flow (of, say, hypersurfaces of Euclidean space)?